# Find missing dates in Impala

Tags: sql, date, impala

I have a table which tracks a person and the day he took medicines

| Subject | Medicine_Date |
| --- | --- |
| Charlie | 09-09-2018 |
| Charlie | 09-10-2018 |
| Charlie | 09-13-2018 |
| Charlie | 09-15-2018 |

I need to find the missing dates in which the subject did not take his medicine.
For example, for the above case my output should be

| Subject | Medicine_Date |
| --- | --- |
| Charlie | 09-11-2018 |
| Charlie | 09-12-2018 |
| Charlie | 09-14-2018 |

In oracle SQL it can be done by creating a calendar table and left joining it to figure out the missing dates. However I am not sure how this can be reciprocated in Impala.

Comment: The approach is the same, though creating the calendar table might be different. If you're reasonably sure each date appears (across all subjects) then you might try using (SELECT medicine_date FROM table GROUP BY medicine_date) AS calendar

Comment: @Josh This works but what if the dates are not exhaustive.

Comment: you'd have generate a table of dates in a sequence using SQL, which would likely be difficult in Impala. I know Snowflake has GENERATOR helpers, but I dont think impala does. Your best bet is to manually build a calendar table 1 time and move the data into hdfs and then register the table so you can join to it in impala. A calendar table will always be useful to have, you can search for them online too.

Comment: @Josh Thanks . But I don't think this is possible for me.